# VB.Net Use datetimepicker as a due date to disable button

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to make a deadline of shutting down the system. Not literally shutting down as I just need to use DateTimePicker to disable a button. Would it be possible to use DateTimePicker to Disable a button whenever you pick an Exact date?

So far I'm just starting to learn how to use datetimepicker and still thinking about the result if that could be possible. Anyone can help?

Comment: all a `datetimepicker` doing is give you a date. you need to use that date and set a timer to compare the current date `Now` with the selected date. this way you can disable your button anytime you want. and everything is possible if you can code it :)

Comment: So basically, you were trying to say that once I've choose a date. A Label will set a countdown timer?

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed Assuming the DateTimerPicker selects the dead-line, the Timer should check, in its `Tick` event: `if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > dateTimePicker1.Value.Ticks) { [The Button].Enabled = false; [The Timer].Enabled = false; }`. This condition: `(yourDtp.Value <> theTargetDate)` is always met.

Comment: @Jimi Oh, my bad. I missed the "deadline" keyword and thought OP simply wanted to enable/disable a button based on a DTP selection.

Comment: @Jimi Where do I put the condition: (yourDtp.Value <> theTargetDate) ?

Comment: Nowhere. You cannot compare dates like that. Set the dead-line with a DateTimepicker, then start a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, with an Interval of 1000 ms. In its `Tick` event, you check whether `DateTime.Now.Ticks > dateTimePicker1.Value.Ticks `(you can also store the DTP's `Value` in a DateTime field). This comparison works. When the condition is met, first disable the Timer, then do what you've got to do.